# Take key values from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How would I take some key values from a string thats formatted like this and save each value into a variable?
`[Alert] <value here> has thrown a <value here> in <value here>.`
I'm really not sure how to go about this... Maybe regex? I'm not very familiar with regex.

Comment: Will all strings conform to "has thrown a" and "in"?

Comment: Yes. All strings will conform to the example that is provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is pretty simple and can be almost identical to your string. Where you want to pick out some words use the match syntax `(.+)` - the period is "any character", and the `+` is "one or more".

Use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on the string with the expression to return an array of matches which you can then [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) into a number of variables (I've called them `a` `b` and `c` here).

```js
// Note: you have to escape the `[` and `]` around "Alert"
// as they are part of regex syntax. `^` and `$`
// signify the start and end of the string respectively
const re = /^\[Alert\] (.+) has thrown a (.+) in (.+)\.$/;
const str = '[Alert] Trump has thrown a tantrum in his Evil Lair.'

const [full, a, b, c] = str.match(re);

console.log(a, b, c);
```